# How to display photos during iOS Shortcuts script

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, shortcuts-app

I am trying to build a workflow in iOS Shortcuts app that helps me sift through and clean up my iOS photos. The idea is to randomly select 20 or so non-favourite photos from iOS Photos app (I have that part working) and pass the result into a loop which - for every photo - displays the photo and then brings up a menu that asks me to either do nothing or sort the current photo into one of two albums (I have the menu and sorting part working, too). I can’t seem to find an action in the Shortcuts app that displays a photo object inside a workflow, though.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Look will display the input in a pop up.

The code blocks:

```
Repeat 20 Times

    Find Photos
    Sort by random
    Limit enabled 
    Get 1 item 

    Quick look

    Choose from menu
    Keep
    Delete

    Keep

    Delete

        Delete photos

    End menu

End repeat
```

A link to the code:

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/1ae0c0d51c614c8caaf3bc9a206f6231

Answer (score 3):

Quick Look will preview passed photos in a modal popup, with Done and Share button.

[image: Quick Look shortcut]